# What's the purpose of By keyword in Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Sample Code:

```
public class RediffLoginPage

{
    Webdriver driver;
    public RediffLoginPage(Webdriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    By username=By.xpath(".//*(@id='login1']");
    By Password=By.name("passwd");
}

public Webelement Emailid()
{
    return driver.findElement(username);
}

public Webelement Password(){return driver.findElement(Password);}
```

In this line,

```
By username=By.xpath(".//*(@id='login1']");
```

what's the purpose of first `By` keyword here?

It's object repository code for a testcase.

Comment: You want someone to explain your own code? This is not how SO works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Class By

[Class By](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) extends *`java.lang.Object`* and is defined as:

```
public abstract class By
extends java.lang.Object

Mechanism used to locate elements within a document. In order to create your own locating mechanisms, it is possible to subclass this class and override the protected methods as required, though it is expected that all subclasses rely on the basic finding mechanisms provided through static methods of this class:

 public WebElement findElement(WebDriver driver) {
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(getSelector()));
     if (element == null)
       element = driver.findElement(By.name(getSelector());
     return element;
 }
```

*`By`* have the following direct known Subclasses:

- [By.ByClassName](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByClassName.html)
- [By.ByCssSelector](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByCssSelector.html)
- [By.ById](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html)
- [By.ByLinkText](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByLinkText.html)
- [By.ByName](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByName.html)
- [By.ByPartialLinkText](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByPartialLinkText.html)
- [By.ByTagName](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByTagName.html)
- [By.ByXPath](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByXPath.html)
- [By.Remotable](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.Remotable.html)